# Javascript function call causes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to call a function "makeQuery" and it's not working, FireBug is telling me:

> missing ; before statement
>   [Break on this error] makeQuery(this.id){\n

I don't quite understand where it wants me to put the ";"

```
$(".predicate").click(function () {
    makeQuery(this.id){
    alert(this.id);
    }
});

function makeQuery(value){
    queryString = queryString+"val="+value+"&";
    variables = variables+1;
    alert(queryString);
    alert(variables);           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
makeQuery(this.id){
alert(this.id);
}
```

with

```
makeQuery(this.id);
alert(this.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra curly brackets at wrapping the alert which doesn't make sense:

```
makeQuery(this.id){\
```

Should be:

```
$(".predicate").click(function () { 
    makeQuery(this.id);
    alert(this.id);      
});
```

The `makeQuery` requires the `;` since you are calling a function.